# Ajax HTTP Request GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript, modular

I am trying to figure out how to make this code cleaner by removing what is generic in order to make it more modular for my other button clicks. I was thinking of using window. global function in coffeescript but wanted to get the community's opinion. FYI, thub and test are going to be removed in order not to hardcode. They will come from login in fields.

Code:

```
$('#button_sandbox').on 'click', ->
  $.ajax
  type: "GET"
  url: start_url + "sandbox/list"
  dataType: "json"
  crossDomain: true
  cache: false

  beforeSend: (xhr) ->
    console.log 'test'
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa("thub" + ":" + "test"));

  error: (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) -> 
    console.dir arguments
    console.log("*| Status ", xhr.status)
    console.log("*| Error", thrownError)
    console.log("*| Ajax", ajaxOptions)

  success: (data) ->

    console.log("Success", data)
    $("#data-box").empty()
    $('#data-box').append """<h1>Sandbox Results</h1>"""
    for i of data
      $('#data-box').append "<br>" +  "<li>" + data[i]
```

Comment: @Jay Blanchard, thank you for the clean up.

Comment: What I have tried to do was pull out the error function and make it a global call but I get the error that xhr is not defined.

Comment: All I need is just a example even with like the beforeSend function.